# How to send message to several specific users Laravel Notification?

Tags: laravel

I studied the Laraval.s notifications. I can not realize how to send bulk notifications to the specific users. I know their ids.

Should I use private channel or broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in laravel there are two way to send notificatons

```
$user=User::find(1) ;
$users=User::all() ;
$user->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice))
// or
Notification::send($users,new InvoicePaid($invoice))
```

so both ways send only one notification but we can send it to single or multiple users.
if you need to send multiple notifications to multiple users you should use loops:

```
$notifications=[new InvoicePaid($invoice) ]
foreach($notifications as $notification)
{
Notification::send($users,$notification)

}
```

also there is a better way to handle this.you can use event and it is better to use event to send notification or perform other task after a specific action. for example define a event as `userRegisterd`. then you can assign one or more listener to this event like `sendNewUserNotification` , `congratulationsNotification`.
in each listener notify the users